# How to upgrade my SharePoint 2013 trial

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have download SharePoint 2013 since four months ago , I worked on it for one month , then I was involved with other products. Yesterday I tried to login to the central administration but I got the following error:-
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

So I am sure that the 180 days trial version is expired , so I have the following questions:-

1. If the trial version expired, will I get this error; HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable ?
2. If the problem is related to the fact that the trial expired, then how I can define a new valid key ?
3. If the problem is not related to the trial version, what I can do to login to the CA again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your farm account's password expired. You can reset this via a [PowerShell](http://info.izzy.org/Blog/archive/2010/08/04/how-to-fix-an-out-of-sync-password-issue-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) script, but since you're in a trial/sandbox envionment you can try this hack which has worked for me in the past:

Change your farm account's password, then change it back to the old value. Then, configure your farm account's password to never expire.